Can MoveIT start from a collision?
We use MoveIT only for homing at the beginning of the process. Sometimes we start in positions that according to model are slightly in collision (e.g. close to a bin wall and the model is not perfectly accurate). Is there a configuration that would allow MoveIT to still perform the move? For example by starting with a move that will "minimize" the collision until it can go normally.
